# Is the efferent arteriole a pathway for filtrate through the nephron ?

Tags: human-biology

I am studying the urinary system. I have to identify what part of the nephron is not a pathway for filtrate. I believed the collecting duct is not a pathway for filtrate because once the filtrate enters this destination it is now referred to as urine, and no longer filtrate. I thought that inferred that it was not a pathway. However, the efferent may also be a strong answer because after glomerular filtration that small molecules that get filtered into the glomerular capsule are identified as filtrate. But the cell and proteins that do not get filtered are not, so not what are they referred to as non-filtered. However, later in the process of urine formation they become secreted back into the bloodstream through the peritubular network into the nephron at the distal convoluted tubule.